# How to add pagination for ajax api response?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am using WordPress API and have WordPress blog posts listed on a php webpage. I would like to add pagination that only shows page numbers when records exist.

Here is my code (updated with the help of the user below)

```
    <div id="results"></div>


     <!-- PAGINATION  -->


                        <ul class="pagination text-center" role="navigation" aria-label="Pagination" data-page="6" data-total="16"> 
     <li class="pagination-previous disabled">Previous<span class="show-for-sr">page</span></li>

     <li class="current"><span class="show-for-sr">You're on page</span> 1</li>

     <li><a href="#"class="page-link" data-page_number ="2" data-per-page="1" aria-label="Page 2">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="page-link" data-page_number ="3" data-per-page="1" aria-label="Page 3">3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="page-link" data-page_number ="4" data-per-page="1"  aria-label="Page 4">4</a></li>

     <li class="ellipsis" aria-hidden="true"></li>

     <li><a href="#" class="page-link" data-page_number ="12" data-per-page="1" aria-label="Page 12">12</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="page-link" data-page_number ="13" data-per-page="1" aria-label="Page 13">13</a></li>

     <li class="pagination-next"><a href="#" aria-label="Next page">Next <span class="show-for-sr">page</span></a></li>
    </ul>


    <script>



    $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(){
          var page = $(this).data('page_number');
         // console.log(page) this works for testing
         myFetchPosts(page);
         }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First here is the WP REST API docs for Pagination: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/

Next:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

// start with page 1
var page = 1;


// Move your API call to a reusable function
function myFetchPosts(page) {
    // use a template literal so we can add the page parameter
    var api_url = `http://example.com/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=1&page=${page}`;
    $.ajax({
            url: api_url,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                var len = response.length;
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    var id = response[i].id;
                    var date = response[i].date;
                    var slug = response[i].slug;
                    var excerpt = response[i].excerpt.rendered;



                    var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                        "<td align='center'>" + (i+1) + "</td>" +
                        "<td align='center'>" + date + "</td>" +
                        "<td align='center'>" + slug + "</td>" +
                        "<td align='center'>" + excerpt + "</td>" +


                        "</tr>" 



                        ;

                    $("#results")
                        .html('') // clear previous page
                        .append(tr_str); // add current page 

                    // increment page so the next time this is called it will fetch the next page
                    page += 1;    

            }    
        } 
    });


    // call our function onload.
    myFetchPosts(page);


    // then for the pagination you need to create some way for the user to click a button for more or something like that and call this function and pass in what ever page you need to get
    someclickablebutton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        myFetchPosts(page);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  There were  few brackets missing.  I have updated my code below but I'm having problems clicking through the pages it keeps returning page one results.  Do you know how to load page two results and remove page one results from the page on clicking the pagination link?

Comment: I have worked this out now but still don't know how to only show pagination numbers when records exist

Comment: I have modified my answer to clear the previous page results when the next page is loaded.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do dynamic pagination? (to only show page number if that page exists)